# Element to inherit properties of an element under it

Tags: html

Here's the code at codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGjyNz

What I am trying is to put blue or green lines under background (gray). As you see, if I set

```
`<li class=''>Launch</li>`
```

[image]

to

```
`<li class='visited'>Launch</li>`
```

[image]

what happens is that it covers the whole gray line completely, while I want it cover, but nicely, with `box-radius` working. Otherwise it is clumsy and has sharp edges.

UPDATE: I want background to cover blue or green, so when gray turns blue or green, it also inherits gray's, with fancy box-radius, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 19 of your css there is a class I added the property z-index to:

`ul.checkout-bar li`

as

`z-index: 100000;`

It's so high because that bar is currently set to 99999.

---

To fix the ending, add:

```
border-radius: 15px;
```

after line 165 in your css. The `:after` never received that property to become curved

Comment: I inserted it after line 25 on your CSS

Comment: didn't work. This has to be after `Launch`. As you can it doesn't end beautiful.

Comment: Ah I see the problem now